# Firebase Cloud Messaging for iOS stop working after upgrade 15.2

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an iOS app that use Firebase Cloud Messages, it works perfectly with iOS 15.1.
After upgrade to iOS 15.2 it stops works, no more notification.
I try to upgrade to latest library on Xcode ( release 8.10.0 ) but nothing change.

My service notify both Android app and iOS app and in Android I receive the notification, but in iOS not receive nothing more.

Comment: I found a solution to this problem. In the event

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) 

I have to inserted this line and so it start works again


`code` Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .unknown)

Hope to be usefull to somebody

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix the same issue updating to the latest Firebase In-App Messaging version (8.11.0-beta)